# Non-trivial $f$ such that $\forall x: f(x) = $ whether $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Tags: calculus

Consider this function:

$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 &\textrm{if } \exists f'(x)\\
    0 &\textrm{if } \nexists f'(x)
\end{cases}
$

Is there any function other than $f(x) = 1$ that satisfies this condition?

Comment: If $f(x_0)=1$, then $f$ must be continuous at $x_0$. Therefore on a neighborhood of $x_0$ one must have $f(x)=0$. Therefore, the set $f^{-1}(1)$ is open. Note that the set $f^{-1}(0)$ cannot contain an interval. Conversely, let $C$ be a closed nowhere dense set of $\mathbb{R}$. Then the characteristic function $f$ of $C^c$  satisfies this property.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Maybe I've misunderstood but shouldn't it be *"Therefore on a neighborhood of $x_0$ one must have $f(x)=\color{red}{1}$."*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, examples like

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 &\textrm{if } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}\\
    0 &\textrm{if } x\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$$

will work.

Comment: Good point. After thinking about it for a few minutes -- any function which is 1 everywhere except in a finite or countably infinite number of points (EDIT: if they are isolated), where it's 0, satisfies the condition. Thanks!

Comment: @int6h Countably infinite is too free. The set in which $f(x)=0$ must be closed. It must also be nowhere dense.

Comment: Not countably (think about $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, $0$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$), but discrete yes!

Comment: As an addendum, unless $f$ is given as surjective, we could also just define $f$ with the discrete, $0$'s case of $f$ and leave $f$ undefined for the rest of $\mathbb{R}$.